# Parsing multiple nested objects from an Array (AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

In my app each "post" has multiple images and each image has 3 different sizes.

This is how my json looks

```
images: [
    {
        image_file: {
            image_file: {
                url: "../air-jordan-v-oreo-1.jpg",
                thumb: {
                    url: "../thumb_air-jordan-v-oreo-1.jpg"
                },
                medium: {
                    url: "../medium_air-jordan-v-oreo-1.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
        image_file: {
            image_file: {
                url: "../air-jordan-v-oreo-2.jpg",
                thumb: {
                    url: "../thumb_air-jordan-v-oreo-2.jpg"
                },
                medium: {
                    url: "../medium_air-jordan-v-oreo-2.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to parse each of the images and show only the MEDIUM size, this is what I have so far:

```
NSString *thumbURL = nil;

if ([_singleRelease[@"images"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [_singleRelease[@"images"] count]) {
    thumbURL = _singleRelease[@"images"][0][@"image_file"][@"image_file"][@"medium"][@"url"];
    if (thumbURL)
    {
        [self.thumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL]];
    }
}
```

This code only shows the FIRST image (size medium) for each post and it displays it in a UIImageView (thumb).

I want to display all the images (size medium) as a slideshow, and I already have that functionality in place except that it display images that I hardcoded in.

I want to change this code and replace it with one that would show my images.

```
self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo4.jpg"],
                   nil];
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to build an array with only the medium sized images?

Comment: What is the log of `_singleRelease` once it has been parsed from the JSON?

Comment: Yeah, only that size. @KyleC

Comment: Is _singleRelase a JSON string? or has it been parsed?

Comment: Are you sure about that structure? `@"image_file"` is a duplicate key in `images[0]`, so there is only one url.

Comment: *"This is how my json looks"*  This is not JSON. Please pretty print the JSON as text.

Comment: Yeah, you can see it here: http://www.soleresource.com/upcoming.json @Kevin

Comment: Yes, you dropped a `},{` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming _singleRelease is a JSON String

```
  NSArray *images = _singleRelease[@"images"];
  NSMutableArray *mediumImages = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (NSDictionary *imageDictionary in images){
      NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageDictionary[@"image_file"][@"medium"]];
      ///This should be done in a background thread
      NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
      [mediumImages addObject:image];
   }

 self.pageImages = [mediumImages copy];
```

Comment: Sorry I wasnt more clear, _singleRelease is a NSDictionary which hold all of my JSON.

Comment: Check updated answer. To summarize, you loop through the "images" array and grab the medium file string from each "image_file". You then add that medium file string to a mediumImages array. After the loop, you assign the mediumImages array to self.pageImages

Comment: I changed a part of your code to: NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageDictionary[@"image_file"][@"image_file"][@"medium"][@"url"]]; and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a minor transcription error, your actual json is this:

```
images: [
    {
        image_file: {
            image_file: {
                url: "../air-jordan-v-oreo-1.jpg",
                thumb: {
                    url: "../thumb_air-jordan-v-oreo-1.jpg"
                },
                medium: {
                    url: "../medium_air-jordan-v-oreo-1.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    },  // <--   
    {   // <-- 
        image_file: {
            image_file: {
                url: "../air-jordan-v-oreo-2.jpg",
                thumb: {
                    url: "../thumb_air-jordan-v-oreo-2.jpg"
                },
                medium: {
                    url: "../medium_air-jordan-v-oreo-2.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You can use KVC set operations:

```
NSArray *urls = [_singleRelease[@"images"] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.image_file.image_file.medium.url"];
```

If you want to filter out duplicate URLS, add `distinct`:

```
... KeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.image_file.image_file.medium.url"
```